# Monomial ideals and Dickson's lemma

Tags: polynomials, monomial-ideals

I am currently revising for my exams and working on questions about monomial ideals and came across this question.

Let I be the ideal of $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ generated by all polynomials of the form $x^iy^j$ with $i,j \in \mathbb{Z}$, $i>0$ and $j \geq (i − 2)^2$. Find a finite set $G \in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ such that $I = <G>$.

I'm not too sure how to go about this, I was thinking about manipulating the inequalities and subbing $j$ into the monomial but can't seem to find a finite set.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Draw the lattice $(i,j)$ and find the minimal vectors, and see if they generate the ideal.

Answer (score 1):

You can write down the first several monomials:

$$i=1, x^1y^{1+k}, k\geq 0 \implies xy\\
i=2, x^2y^k, k\geq 0 \implies x^2, x^2y, x^2y^2,...\\
i=3, x^3 y^{1+k}, k\geq 0 \implies x^3y,...\\
i=4, x^4 y^{4+k}, k\geq 0 \implies x^4y^4, ...$$

From this point on, it is very clear that every monomial is divisable by some previous one. See if you can find a finite bases from those.